# Why does this width watching AngularJS directive not work upon switching Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have two Bootstrap tabs on a page and each tab displays a list. I want each list item to be a square and wrote this AngularJS directive to set the height of each list item to be equal to its Bootstrap controlled dynamic width:

```
app.directive('squareDiv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element,attr) {
            scope.getWidth = function () {
                return element.width();
            };
            scope.$watch(scope.getWidth, function (width) {
                element.css({ 
                    height: width + 'px'
                });
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

When I load this page, the first tab's list items show up as squares which means the directive is working. But when I click on another tab, the list items there have the default height of 100 px. When I switch back to the first tab, even the list items there have the default height now.

What is going wrong here?

UPDATE 1:

Here is the link to a plunker that illustrates this problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pc7keuRXR9R3U6AhZmFE?p=preview

UPDATE 2:

Plunker with Bootstrap replaced by UI-Bootstrap that still has the same problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/rLE1wUAHKzJP6FVnGF6b?p=preview

UPDATE 3:

Plunker with watch for tab switch instead of width change (workaround for the original problem of width watch not working correctly; will need to use a separate directive for adapting to width changes due to window resizing): http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4Goe0cexq979JsIcBxl?p=preview

I would still like to understand why the width watch stops working correctly after a tab switch.

Comment: It may be because the tab is hidden, so its contents don't have dimensions yet. Anyway, it would help if you made a plunker or something.

Comment: Thats right, a plunker could be of great help!

Comment: Here is the link to a plunker that illustrates this behavior: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pc7keuRXR9R3U6AhZmFE?p=preview Directive works on tab 1 but not on tab 2

Comment: This directive doesn't even work correctly; it's throwing `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` before it completes a full cycle on a single tab.

Comment: @Claies, this error appears only in the plunker but not in my actual project. Could it not be related to my code but Plunker's?

Comment: @Price - I have absolutely no knowledge about angular, but can't you just use bootstraps `shown.bs.tab` event to set the `height` of the `.holder` elements inside the list items ? Here is an example [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3mshY7IpXzcNTu44DRi2?p=preview). Just like i said i have no clue if this is the correct way to do this with angular, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, David! :) I can definitely use this in my project but would still like to understand why the Angular watcher is not firing as it is supposed to.

Comment: @Price - Sure, no problem. It's probably better to wait and see if someone with a better background on angular can tell you what's going on here. In general i always rely on bootstrap events whenever i want to manipulate content inside bootstraps components, but since i have no angular skills, there may be a totally different solution to your problem, which i am not aware of. ;-)

Comment: @Price I would suggest switching over to the Bootstrap Angular version as dekztah suggest since your digest is off. If not we can use to our advantage that the digest is completely off and just use the old width value, which is a bit unorthodox. http://plnkr.co/edit/2TQIrvMuxiEU1cwePfhG?p=preview

Comment: @jjbskir, switching to ui-bootstrap also didn't fix the one cycle lag of the directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/rLE1wUAHKzJP6FVnGF6b?p=preview

Comment: @Price got it. I guess this is just one of the quirks of working with angular. I submitted a answer that will work, but I have no idea how to fix the underlying angular issue.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13221#issuecomment-152989640.

Answer (score 8):

Your directive's watcher is one digest cycle behind of what's happening. If you look closely enough, you will see that the very first tab clicking does not do much (nothing logged to console). What you see is your active tab's elements being resized to the hidden tabs elements heights. So the hidden tab's heights are correct. I would strongly advise using the angular version of bootstrap instead of the generic one. That way everything (events) will be in the control of angular.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

**edit:** this maybe useful for understanding digest cycle triggering and callbacks outside angular : http://school.codecraftpro.com/courses/angularjs-1x-fundamentals/lectures/392422

**edit2**: also useful https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

Comment: Thanks! I thought Angular was compatible with the standard Bootstrap. How were you able to determine that the watcher is one digest cycle behind?

Comment: On pageload you will see 4-4 console logs. After clicking Tab 2 there is nothing. Then it comes back again. So this is basically because bootstrap js click is not registered within angular. Wrapping it in a directive can solve this but since the angular ui guys have already did this, you could spare some time :)

Comment: correction: not registered within that digest cycle, but one cycle later

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I have created a new plunker based on ui-bootstrap but the directive still seems to be one digest cycle behind. Could you please check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/rLE1wUAHKzJP6FVnGF6b?p=preview ?

Comment: ui.bootstrap.tabs has a setting for firing custom expression on tab select.
please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/s5JepBEPMkvGW4Qbm4PH?p=preview
Even though this is a different approach, my answer is still valid for the original question.

Comment: Thanks! After switching tabs a few times, the height goes off in the above plunker. And the original question still remains: why does the width watcher not work (even with ui-bootstrap)?

Comment: Is there a way to force our directive to sync up with the digest cycle?

Comment: i think what you experience is only because angular animate is also included as lib. if you are not using it and you only included it because of the sample code on angular ui bootstrap site is also using it, than you can remove it. Otherwise i don't know what else can be done. Nevertheless its not the same digest cycle problem anymore, but probably the select expression executes before the tab contents are rendered. Here is one more: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4Goe0cexq979JsIcBxl?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93925/discussion-between-price-and-dekztah).

Answer (score 0):

We know that the digest of bootstrap tabs switching is ahead of the width of your divs. So instead of watching for the width of your divs to change, let's instead watch when your tab changes. When the tab changes, let's wait 1 ms to make sure we are on the next digest cycle. Then get the width and update your box height.

I have no idea why this is the case, but here is the solution that will work.

Here is a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UyxNI9gsOyBg6sNdcvYs?p=preview)

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module("app",['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('mainController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.tabs = [
        {'title': 'Tab 1'},
        {'title': 'Tab 2'}
    ];
}]);

app.directive('squareDiv', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            scope.active = function() {
                return scope.tabs.filter(function(tab){
                    return tab.active;
                })[0];
            };

            scope.$watch(scope.active, function (tabActive) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.css({ 
                        height: element.width()
                    });
                }, 1);

            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Per comments on the other answer, we would need to remove the reference to ngAnimate to prevent switching of tabs a few times from messing up the heights in this solution.

Comment: actually, if you also include requestAnimationFrame inside the $timeout, that would prevent layout thrashing, and you could keep nganimate.
see: http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing/

Comment: Very interesting! I just updated the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/UyxNI9gsOyBg6sNdcvYs?p=preview - to use requestAnimationFrame  and it seems to be working. Also the other big issue seems to be what @ExpertSystem brought up that jQuery is converting the width of 100% to 100px, which can't be good either.