# AngularJS directive not working when switching Bootstrap tabs or back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing problem with working with directive.

AngularJS directive not working when switching Bootstrap tabs or if I will go back and again if I will try.

I feel there is some issue with jQuery library itself.. what I am using for resize column.
URL : http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#samples

**My Directive Code:**

```
define([
  'angular',
  'app',
  'lodash',
  'jquery',
  'colResizeable'
],
function(angular, app, _, $) {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('grafana.directives')
    // .module('grafana.controllers')
    .directive('columnResizeable', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            elem.colResizable({
              liveDrag: true,
              gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip'></div>",
              draggingClass: "dragging",
              onDrag: function() {
                //trigger a resize event, so paren-witdh directive will be updated
                $(window).trigger('resize');
              }
            });
          });
        }
      };
    });
});
```

My Html Code :

```
    <table id="common_query_editor" class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-if="!panel.procesChart" column-resizeable>

   // Some code it there
    </table>
```

I debug this and get to know, some html content is adding when page loads.

```
<div class="JCLRgrips" style="width: 1208px;"><div class="JCLRgrip" style="left: 202px; height: 91px;"><div class="grip"></div><div class="JColResizer"></div></div><div class="JCLRgrip" style="left: 403px; height: 91px;"><div class="grip"></div><div class="JColResizer"></div></div><div class="JCLRgrip" style="left: 604px; height: 91px;"><div class="grip"></div><div class="JColResizer"></div></div><div class="JCLRgrip" style="left: 805px; height: 91px;"><div class="grip"></div><div class="JColResizer"></div></div><div class="JCLRgrip" style="left: 1007px; height: 91px;"><div class="grip"></div><div class="JColResizer"></div></div><div class="JCLRgrip JCLRLastGrip" style="left: 1209px; height: 91px;"></div></div>
```

But next time this content is not loading.
Some html behaviour is differing in both time.

I was checking this link : [Why does this width watching AngularJS directive not work upon switching Bootstrap tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414355/why-does-this-width-watching-angularjs-directive-not-work-upon-switching-bootstr)
but not able to find any solution.
How I can **watch** if that directive is loading.. I put the console inside directive but its not triggering the console. `scope.$watch`

Please help me..

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?